# SingleSelectionModel<Tab> won't work tabPane is "null"

Tags: java, javafx

Good day everyone!

I am trying to get a button in a different fxml file to switch tabs when I click it. This is the minimal reproducible example (I hope) I came up with:

Main

```
package com.example.test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class TestTabMain extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(TestTabMain.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 800, 600 );
        stage.setTitle("testTabSwitching");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

TestTabController: (controls main file)

```
package com.example.test;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class TestTabController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TabPane testPane;

    @FXML
    private Tab testTab1;

    @FXML
    private Tab testTab2;

    @FXML
    private Tab testTab3;

    SingleSelectionModel<Tab> selectionModel;

    @FXML
    private void selectTestTab3(){
        selectionModel.select(testTab3);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        selectionModel = testPane.getSelectionModel();
    }
}
```

ButtonController:

```
package com.example.test;

import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class ButtonController extends TestTabController implements Initializable {

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        super.initialize(url, resourceBundle);

    }
}
```

Main fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<VBox alignment="CENTER"  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="com.example.test.TestTabController">
    <TabPane fx:id="testPane">
        <tabs>
            <Tab fx:id="testTab1" text="test1"></Tab>
            <Tab fx:id="testTab2" text="test2"></Tab>
            <Tab fx:id="testTab3" text="test3"></Tab>
        </tabs>
        <fx:include source="button.fxml"/>
    </TabPane>

</VBox>
```

Button fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="com.example.test.ButtonController"
            prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
    <Button onAction="#selectTestTab3">switch</Button>
</AnchorPane>
```

Basically the issue seems to lie in the fact that the button be in a different file. It works perfectly when I don't use the include, but I need it in a different file because it's in a different part of the GUI, which will be used to look up dates in agenda, but first it needs to switch to the tab containing said agenda. Whenever I press the button, I get this error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/Users/danie/IdeaProjects/test/target/classes/com/example/test/button.fxml
/D:/Users/danie/IdeaProjects/test/target/classes/com/example/test/hello-view.fxml:17

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2685)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$IncludeElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1156)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:756)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2808)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2634)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
    at com.example.test/com.example.test.TestTabMain.start(TestTabMain.java:14)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:474)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:447)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:446)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.TabPane.getSelectionModel()" because "this.testPane" is null
    at com.example.test/com.example.test.TestTabController.initialize(TestTabController.java:35)
    at com.example.test/com.example.test.ButtonController.initialize(ButtonController.java:12)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2655)
    ... 17 more
Exception running application com.example.test.TestTabMain
```

I have been stuck on this since yesterday and tried all the solutions I could find here and on the internet, but to no avail. Can you help me out? Thank you!

Comment: [mcve] please .. including the app where you load the fxml

Comment: @kleopatra edited for minimal reproducible example...I hope. Sorry, I'm still pretty new at this.

Comment: shouldn't the button be outside the TabPane? included as child of the VBox?

Comment: @kleopatra this is one issue. The other issue is why ButtonController needs to extend the TabController?

Comment: @MissChanandlerBong yeah the setup looks a bit weird

Comment: answering my last comment: definitely - the NPE covers the exception thrown for the mis-location: "Unable to coerce VBoxAT338485d3 to class javafx.scene.control.Tab". As @MissChanandlerBong already noted: extending is not a good tool:  afaik (not a fxml expert, so take it with a grain of salt :) there is no counterpart of extending on the fxml side, that is the button.fxml is _only_ injecting the ui defined in itself, _not_ the ui defined main.fxml. You probably want to pass parameters between both.

Comment: You seem to be *very* confused about what inheritance means. `ButtonController extends TestTabController` means that every `ButtonController` instance is also a `TextTabController` instance. `public class TestTabController { private TabPane testPane ; }` means that every `TestTabController` instance has a field called `testPane`. Your FXML setup ensures one instance of `TestTabController` is created when `hello-view.fxml` is loaded, which has `testPane` initialized, and one instance of `ButtonController` is created when `button.fxml` is loaded. ...

Comment: There's no `fx:id = "testPane"` in `button.fxml`, so the `testPane` field in your `ButtonController` instance, which is inherited from `TestTabController` is null. So you get a null pointer exception.